# Mortarboard badge

Tags: discussion, badges

Curious how earning this badge works - it says "earned at least 200 reputation in a single day" - which I did, on Feb 9th (earned 273) - yet I was not awarded the badge. Is it because of the way UTC time is used or am I missing something?

Comment: My first guess is that the +100 account association bonus doesn't count.

Comment: Ah, I bet you're right. I didn't even think to look at the break down for how the reputation was earned that day. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the badge FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68395/13531):

> - Earned more than 200 reputation from vote types in a single day
>
>   - For the purposes of this badge, "vote types" include:
>
>     - upvotes on your questions
>     - upvotes on your answers
>     - acceptances of your answers
>     - bounties being awarded to your answers
>   - Reputation points earned for associating accounts or for accepting other users' answers to your own questions do **not** count for the badge.

Since 100 of your 273 points were from the association bonus, you came up just short of the 200 rep necessary for the badge. That day also will not count towards the Epic or Legendary badge.

Comment: Great explanation - thanks!